# What is the difference between fontSize and textScaleFactor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

The default for `fontSize` is `14.0`. Therefore, `textScaleFactor: 2.0` appears to be the same as `fontSize: 28.0` as seen in my code example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title')),
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("Jane", textScaleFactor: 2.0),
            new Text(" Doe", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0)),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

What are the pros and cons? Are there any recommendations when to use one or another in specific cases?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no difference between them in the rendering. What changes are their purpose.

Font-size is usually a per-component value. While the scale factor is more global. The fact that you can override the scale factor directly on the `Text` is just a bonus.

In your typical application, you'll have the following:

```
MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 2.0),
  child: Whatever(
    child: Text("Foo", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
  ),
);
```

Basically, consider `textScaleFactor` as a zoom option. While font-size is used to separate a title from its content.

Comment: Actually the textScaleFactor can be handled by the user in the "settings" menu of the cell phone. if you override this property, the user changes will have no effect.
But if you use FontSize, then the size will change when the user changes his(or her) settings.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I understand, `textScaleFactor`is used for accessibility.

There is an Android system option that increases text size (not the overall UI scale).

There doesn't seem to be a technical difference.

From the `TextStyle` docs:

```
  /// During painting, the [fontSize] is multiplied by the current
  /// `textScaleFactor` to let users make it easier to read text by increasing
  /// its size.
```

Answer (score 3):

- `fontSize` **is overridden** by device **system font size** configurations.
- `textScaleFactor` **overrides** device **system font size** configurations.